# Transpose Pandas dataframe but keep only nonzero values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**DataFrame:**

Let me clarify my question. My `pandas.DataFrame` looks like this

```
data = [
    ['word11', 'word12', 'word13', 'word14', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ['word21', 'word22', 'word23', 'word24', 0, -3, 34, 0, 0],
    ['word31', 'word32', 'word33', 'word34', 0, 1.6, 0, 0, 0],
    ['word41', 'word42', 'word43', 'word44', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'])
```

**Output to be generated:**

From this, I want to get a data frame which looks like

```
    word1   word2   word3   word4  C1   C2  C3  C4  C5
0  word11  word12  word13  word14   0  0.0   0   0   0
1  word21  word22  word23  word24   0 -3.0  34   0   0
2  word31  word32  word33  word34   0  1.6   0   0   0
3  word41  word42  word43  word44   0  0.0   0   0   0
```

**My Program:**

Here is what I did to get the above data frame

```
primary_columns = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']
transposing_columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5']
transposed_df = df.melt(id_vars=primary_columns, value_vars=transposing_columns)
compare_columns = primary_columns + ['value']
```

Then I divided the data frame into two based on the value of 'value' column and dropped duplicates.

```
nonzero_df = transposed_df[transposed_df['value'] != 0]
zero_df = transposed_df[transposed_df['value'] == 0]
zero_df = zero_df.drop_duplicates(subset=compare_columns, keep='first')
df = nonzero_df.append(zero_df)
```

Which gives me the following output

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df

    word1   word2   word3   word4 variable  value
0  word21  word22  word23  word24       C2   -3.0
1  word31  word32  word33  word34       C2    1.6
2  word21  word22  word23  word24       C3   34.0
3  word11  word12  word13  word14       C1    0.0
4  word21  word22  word23  word24       C1    0.0
5  word31  word32  word33  word34       C1    0.0
6  word41  word42  word43  word44       C1    0.0
```

**Issue:**

I don't want to see `df.iloc[4]` and `df.iloc[5]`.

If the values of `word1`, `word2`, `word3` and  `word4` are the same but the difference is only in the `value` column, keep the row with non-zero value and drop the row with 0 value. I don't care about the value of the column `variable`.

How can I achieve this?

**NOTE:**

1. My data frame is huge. It contains close to million rows more than 15  `Word*` type columns and more than 115  `C*` type columns(`word*` and `C*` are the column names I used for my example).
2. I use `Python 2.7` with `Pandas 0.17`.

Comment: I guess you could just use logical indexing if I get you right. Try `print(df[df.value == 1])`

Comment: What is the logic that you want to keep one row with `0` and the rest are all `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your task is not a transposition, but something like *stack*,
limited to non-zero values, with some additions namely, for rows
containing all zeroes (in *C1* thru *C4*) you want the output to contain
values of *word1* thru *word3* and:

- *variable == 'C1'*,
- *value == 0*.

To do it, compute 2 intermediate variables:

1. A *Series* containing the stack of *C1* thru *C4* columns, with
   *word1* thru *word3* moved to the index and the last level of the index
   renamed to *variable*:

   ```
   s = df.set_index(['word1', 'word2', 'word3']).stack().rename('value')
   s.index.rename('variable', level=3, inplace=True)
   ```

   For your input data, the result is:

   ```
   word1   word2   word3   variable
   word11  word12  word13  C1          0
                           C2          0
                           C3          0
                           C4          0
   word21  word22  word23  C1          0
                           C2          1
                           C3          1
                           C4          0
   word31  word32  word33  C1          1
                           C2          0
                           C3          0
                           C4          1
   Name: value, dtype: int64
   ```
2. Output result for rows containing all zeroes (in *C1* thru *C4*):

   ```
   dfZer = df[df.loc[:, 'C1':'C4'].sum(axis=1) == 0].loc[:, 'word1':'word3']\
      .assign(variable='C1', value=0)
   ```

   For your data the result is:

   ```
       word1   word2   word3 variable  value
   0  word11  word12  word13       C1      0
   ```

Then generate the final result as:

```
pd.concat([s[s > 0].reset_index(), dfZer], sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

Note that:

- `s[s > 0]` drops elements with value of *0*,
- `reset_index()` coverts it back to a DataFrame,
- `dfZer` provides the result for "all zeroes" input rows,
- `ignore_index=True` "regenerates" the index in the result.

To trace how this solution works, print also `s[s > 0].reset_index()`
and everything should be clear.

Comment: Thank you.  Your solution saves me from transposing huge dataframe. This works great with 
`pd.concat([s[s != 0].reset_index(), dfZer], sort=False, ignore_index=True)`
for small dataset with Python 3.7.  But I am having issue with 
`s = df.set_index(['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']).stack().rename('value')` on older Pandas version.  I got `TypeError:'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it using 
`s = df.set_index(['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']).stack()
s.rename('value':s.values)
`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to keep all the `1`'s in each row. And in case there are all `0` on the row, keep any value:

```
d = (df.melt(['word1','word2','word3'])
   .sort_values('value', ascending=False)
)

d[~d.duplicated(['word1','word2','word3']) | d['value']]
```

Output:

```
     word1   word2   word3 variable  value
2   word31  word32  word33       C1      1
4   word21  word22  word23       C2      1
7   word21  word22  word23       C3      1
11  word31  word32  word33       C4      1
0   word11  word12  word13       C1      0
```

Comment: Thank you. You get it right and your answer is exactly what I am looking for. This works perfectly after transposition. However, I am accepting Valdi's because it saved me from a memory-intensive transpose operation. Thank you very much once again